# AWS PowerShell CLI: How to obtain list of Policies applied to an Instance

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-policies

I have a lot of instances running an an AWS Account. Each is attached to a different IAM Role (1). I can review the Role via the Management Console (2) and see the attached Policies (3).
[image]

[image]

I want to obtain a list of these programmatically.
I have written some powershell.

```
$region = 'eu-west-3'
Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region $region
$ec2 = Get-EC2Instance    
$ec2list = $ec2.Instances

$ec2listdetails = $ec2list | ForEach-Object {
    $properties = [ordered]@{
    Name = ($_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty tags | Where-Object -Property Key -eq Name).value
    InstanceState = $_.State.Name
    InstanceID = $_.InstanceId
    InstanceType = $_.InstanceType
    Platform = $_.Platform
    PlatformDetails = $_.PlatformDetails
    LaunchTime = $_.launchtime
    KeyName = $_.KeyName
    AmiID = $_.ImageID
    ImageName = (Get-EC2Image -ImageId $_.ImageID).Name
    IamRoleID = $_.IamInstanceProfile.Id
    IamRoleARN = $_.IamInstanceProfile.Arn
    PrivateIP = $_.PrivateIpAddress
    SubnetId = $_.SubnetId
    SubnetName = (Get-EC2Subnet -subnetid ($_.SubnetId) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty tags | Where-Object -Property Key -eq Name).value
    NetworkInterfaceId = $_.networkinterfaces.networkinterfaceid
    MAC = $_.networkinterfaces.MacAddress
    VPCId = $_.VpcId
    VPCName = (Get-EC2VPC -vpcid ($_.vpcId) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty tags | Where-Object -Property Key -eq Name).value
    AZ = $_.placement.AvailabilityZone
    SG = $_.SecurityGroups.GroupName
    BackupTag = ($_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty tags | Where-Object -Property Key -eq BackupTag).value
    ProductTag = ($_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty tags | Where-Object -Property Key -eq Product).value
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties
}
 
$ec2listdetails | Sort-Object -Property SubnetName | Export-Csv -Path "$($PWD.Path)\ec2-report-$region.csv"
```

Get-EC2Instance returns the following properties:
[image]

The returned property is the IamInstanceProfile, I can't seem to find the correct command to get all Policies attached to that Profile programmatically?

Any ideas?

Comment: You need https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-attached-role-policies.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-role-policies.html to list the inline and attached managed policies.

Comment: The problem is that list-attached-role-policies requires the --role-name parameter which is the friendly name of the role. However, Get-EC2Instance does not return the friendly name it returns the "Instance Profile ARN".

Comment: The last part of the arn is the name.

Answer (score 0):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feAhG.png)You can use this in order to get the Role and that will take only the human readable
text

.....
$ec2listdetails = $ec2list | ForEach-Object {
$s = $*.IamInstanceProfile.arn  # u need this object to be split and create variable
$properties = [ordered]@{
Name = ($* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty tags | Where-Object -Property Key -eq Name).value
InstanceState = $_.State.Name
.
.
.
IamRoleARN = ($s -split "/" )[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feAhG.png) #use this to get the Role name only not the entire arn
.
.
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).